# How can I add the android support library to my netbeans project

Tags: android, netbeans, android-support-library

specifically I just want to import ActionBarActivity to my net beans project... you would think that this would be a simple enough task, however that does not seem to be the case. I would be so grateful if there was a fairly simple way to do this... And please bear in mind I am on lesson one of the first android app tutorial on the android developers website so probably wont understand if you give me a hugely complex and technical answer.

Comment: I believe the Jar file is in your sdk folder, should you have installed the support libraries using the sdk manager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the required file (eg. android-support-v13.jar) from the SDK directory into the libs folder in your project. Eg. from android-sdk/extras/android/support/v13.

First of all make sure to install the support lib with SDK manager.

Comment: This answer is wrong. This works for library that doesn't have resources. For appcompat v7 this doesn't work (and I still don't have any solution to import a library with resources)

Answer (score 0):

Open project properties, select "JAR Libraries", choose "Custom location", browse to desired directory and press open. You'll have your jar in "Referenced JRA libraries" below. Now just press OK.

PS.
It's do not download libraries manually, instead use SDK manager.
Open "Tools"->"Android SDK manager" and install desired library.